# How to install mlpack header files in /usr?

Tags: software-installation, 16.04

How do I install `mlpack` into the proper `usr/bin` and `usr/include` folders? I followed the website's guide and ended up creating my `include` and `bin` folders in my `build` folder after running the command (final step):

```
make install
```

Please help.

Website's guide: http://www.mlpack.org/docs/mlpack-2.0.2/doxygen.php?doc=build.html

Here's where it ends up:

[image: Here's where it ends up]

Comment: Did you remember to change to root (or use `sudo`) to run `make install`?

Comment: Yeah, I used `sudo make install`. How does one change to root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mlpack files will be installed to /usr/local/, by using `sudo make install`

```
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mlpack
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mlpack/core
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mlpack/core/arma_extend
-- Installing: /usr/local/include/mlpack/core/arma_extend/Cube_extra_bones.hpp
.
.
-- Set runtime path of "/usr/local/bin/mlpack_sparse_coding" to ""
```

The complete "mlpack-install.log.txt" (599 lines) : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNeExtdHJ6NmN6R1E/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh wow, it's not going to be in usr/include? I checked the directories you mentioned and found it, but the website mentions other locations

Comment: The text in mlpack says /usr/local/. ..... I think it's the file README.x or INSTALL .